# How do airplane in-seat power detection circuits work?

Tags: power-supply

Airplane in-seat AC line-voltage power outlets have limited available current/power. I remember reading that laptops or laptop power adapters can somehow detect this and inform the laptop that it needs to limit power consumption. If this is true, they must have detection circuits of some kind. How do these work?

Comment: It probably just detects the voltage sagging on the outlet which would work with pretty much any power limited outlet.

Comment: @DKNguyen that is not necessarily true; a traditional mains circuit breaker is not going to notably sag before tripping.  At least going by reports of traveller experience, these outlets are not "limited" but rather "protected" in that when they experience an overload they cut out *entirely* and must be manually reset by the cabin crew.

Comment: I trip them all the time with my laptop charger (large inrush when plugging it in) but they always seem to reset themselves, I have never had to ask a flight attendant to reset one for me.

Comment: I worked on the design of several of these types of systems; USB has a method for the charger to let the device know how much current is available for charging. This type of thing does not exist for AC power adapters.

Comment: @akohlsmith Sure, I know about USB PD standard.

Comment: @AntonTykhyy well there is the spec, and then there are PD controllers which implement the spec. If you’ve got a question about the former that would be on-topic, but unless you had built a circuit using one of the controllers and it wasn’t working right then asking about a specific part in a theoretical or commercial circuit would probably be off topic (I think).

Comment: @ChrisStratton: On the contrary, EE.SE is **precisely** a "how things work SE". That's the very definition of engineering.

Comment: Sorry Dave, but no it isn't - without documentation this is unanswerable, and thus outside our mission (for that matter **the asker has no evidence this capability even exists**).  It's the same problem as all other consumer product usage and repair questions.